# How do I calculate the derivative of a function y with a specific value x in octave?

Tags: octave

Like this:

```
   x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 5);
```

So x will be equal to: [0, pi./2, pi, 3*pi./2, 2*pi];

```
   y = sin(x);
```

Then how do I calculate the derivative of y with those 5 x values?
The output should be 1, 0, -1, 0 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `deriv` function from the optim package:

```
dx = deriv(@sin, pi/2)
```

Eventually you have to install and load the package first. In ubuntu this can be done by typing

```
sudo apt-get install octave-optim
```

in a terminal and then start octave and run:

```
pkg load optim
```